# Solr replication can be done with automatic dictionary update?

Tags: solr

I am wondering if Solr replication can be done with some key dictionary files update. I am building an index from a build machine and then these will be replicated to a few real production solr machines. One issue I have is that I have dictionary files (synonym and stemming related) which are used in index building in the build machine and those files need to be synchronized with replication. Does Solr have inherent mechanism of supporting it or do I have to program/script something on top of replication (does it have some kind of hook which can be called at the end of replication)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr does support replication of configuration files, but the ones that are within the Conf folder.

Check [How_are_configuration_files_replicated](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#How_are_configuration_files_replicated.3F)

Comment: Great.Thanks! So the SOLR will be restarted after that or the core in question will be reloaded to use the new configuration files?

Comment: after replication .. usually the cores are reloaded and new searches are opened.